# Default Rails 5.2.1.1 Content Security Policy (CSP) "style-src 'unsafe-inline'" gets violated

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, content-security-policy

**what I want to do**

Just learning Rails -- trying to add some fun styling and script to a default `rails new appname` project. Followed the [MDB implementation guide here](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/jquery/problems-with-pro-components-2/), meaning adding styles and scripts under `vendor/assets/(stylesheets or javascripts)` and including the files in the assets pipeline.

**the problem is**

Bootstrap, for example, gets included into the markup within its own little `<link>` tag, but gets blocked by CSP, which says:

```
Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/bootstrap.self-084....css?body=1'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'unsafe-inline'".
```

**what did not help**

I tried finding where the CSP is defined exactly, but it is not so easy for a brown-noser like myself to navigate in this pretty dense scaffold.
Tried fiddling in
`/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb`
and
`'vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.2.1.1/lib/rails/application_controller.rb'` -> but with no success.

Tried to overwrite content_security_policy inside my `app/asstes/controllers/application_controller.rb` *class ApplicationController*, like so:

```
content_security_policy do |p|
  p.style_src "self"
  p.script_src "self"
end
```

but the error message in the console stays the same.

I know about chrome plugins I can use to disable and test CSP, but it feels like cheating.

**question**

How do I tweak the CSP header options so the Rails app allows for the asset-piped assets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The CSP should be defined in `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` if you are using an up to date Rails version.

Can you configure it there?

Comment: thanks for a reponse! Well, it looks like this (a part):

`#   policy.script_src  :self, :https`
`#   policy.style_src   :self, :https`

as you can see, it already does not mention the "unsafe-inline" header value, that causes the error and the files to not be included. Actually, the `:self` option mentioned in the file sounds like something I would really like to set.